# Proper way to user Angular resource service $save function

Tags: php, angularjs, angularjs-resource

I'm working with angular resources trying to use the angular $save function.

By default $save sends the model back to the service URL.  However, it looks like it expects the model to be returned to the service (my model is empty if I don't do this).  I was wondering what the best way to return messages and errors to the controller is.

My solution was to create a new class in my PHP that has an errors array that stores any errors encountered in processing and a field that stores the model for returning.  It's then send back and processed in the call-back function:

```
$scope.ApplyChanges=function(){
   console.log("saving...");
    $scope.user.$save(function(data){
      console.log(data);
      if (data.errors.length>0){
         for (error in data.errors){
            $scope.alerts.push({type:'danger', msg: data.errors[error].msg});
         }
         $scope.user=User.get({id:data.data.UserName});
      } else {
         $scope.user=User.get({id:data.data.UserName});
         $scope.alerts.push({type:'success', msg: "User data saved successfully"});
      }
    }, function(err){
         $scope.alerts.push({type:'danger', msg: "There was a problem saving your data: " + err});
    });
```

these lines here: `$scope.user=User.get({id:data.data.UserName});` I had to use because if I just assigned my `$scope.user` to `data.data`, user was no longer using the service and I would get an error when I tried to `ApplyChanges` again.

So, is there a way to do this more seemlessly? As it is I have to make an additional call back to get the model. Should I send an error only if there's an error and then have an additional callback to get the model?  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your server should return errors with relevant [HTTP error status codes](http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html#) (see 4xx and 5xx codes). That way, you only handle errors in the error callback:

```
function onError (response){
    switch (response.status) {
    case 400:
    case 404:
    //etc... 
        response.data.errors.forEach(function(error){
            $scope.alerts.push({type:'danger', msg: error.msg});
        });
        break;
    case 500:
        $scope.alerts.push({type:'danger', msg: "There was a problem saving your data: " + response.data});
        break;
    }
}
```

That said, if $scope.user is a [$resource instance](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource#usage_returns), then you do not have to get it again from the server, the $save() method will not change the object.

To copy values from the 'user' object retrieved from the server into the $scope.user just use [angular.extend()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.extend)

```
angular.extend($scope.user, data) //this updates $scope.user with data attributes.
```

Is worth noting that `angular.extend` does not perform a deep copy, if needed, use [jQuery.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/):

```
jQuery.extend(true, $scope.user, data)
```

Comment: Maybe I should be more specific, if there was a user input error, and my server side validation for one reason or another kicked it back, so the call was successful, but the user was not.

Comment: Also, I've noticed that if I do not return the object to the save function then the model is emptied.

Comment: If a server side validation failed, then the server should respond a [422 Unprocessable Entity](http://restpatterns.org/HTTP_Status_Codes/422_-_Unprocessable_Entity) or a [409 Conflict](http://httpstatus.es/409) or the appropriate status code with the error data in the payload.

Comment: Which version of angular are you using? I've used $resource in 1.2.0-rc3 and it does not change the model. If you need to copy values from the "user" object retrieved from the server to the $scope.user then you can use [angular.extend](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.extend) `angular.extend($scope.user, data.data)`

Comment: I'm using 1.2.0-rc3. Slightly unrelated, but yeah, everytime $save is called my resource is cleared.  I'll give the extend a try.  My goal is to send a detailed message as to what failed, though the 422 error does make sense because they'd be trying to mess with me by bypassing my api.